# Will there be a "last call" when the API is about to be released?

Tags: discussion, contest

I understand the contest ends when version 1.0 of the API will be released, but will there be any indication when this time comes? So that you know you can allocate one last weekend for final fixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there will be some sort of indication.

If nothing else, we'll probably use version 0.9 as a "nothing but bug fixes"/release-candidate-ish phase.

Comment: Lemme guess, 6-8 weeks...